# Trying to get id of a div using its class

Tags: javascript, dom, dojo

I have a strange problem, I am trying to implement drag and drop using dojo, this all works fine. However I need to attain the id of all divs with a certain class, I have been unable to do so using the dojo.query method e.g. :

```
        var totalNumDays = dojo.query(".shiftDropper");
        console.log(totalNumDays.id);
```

This results is undefined ?

I have also tried using the following:

```
var totalNumDays = dojo.query(".shiftDropper");
var idName = totalNumDays.attr("id");
console.log(idName);
```

However this returns the results in a strange way it returns the id's but as an object ?
If anyone could point me the right direction it would be great, I will include the HTML source to give u guys a clearer idea of the problem:

```
        <div id="day1dropper" class="shiftDropper">
            <table class="tableDropTarget" id="day1" dojoType="dojo.dnd.Target" accept="shift" copyOnly="false">
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        <div id="clearButton">Clear Shifts</div>
    </div>

    <div id="day2dropper" class="shiftDropper">
            <table class="tableDropTarget" id="day1" dojoType="dojo.dnd.Target" accept="shift" copyOnly="false">
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        <div id="clearButton">Clear Shifts</div>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
 var totalNumDays = dojo.query(".shiftDropper")[0];
 console.log(totalNumDays.id);
```

dojo.query returns an array.

Comment: so does dojo.query(...).attr() ... so: dojo.query(".shoftDropper").attr("id")[0] if you know the first/only element is the one you want.